# Omitting covariates in a tbl_regression from gtsummary package

Tags: r, gtsummary

Using gtsummary I want to display my adjusted linear regression model without
displaying the covariates. So far I have not found a solution for this. Does anyone know how best to do this?

For example, using the code below, I would like to diplay the first row which shows the cylinder variable and omit the subsequent rows (disp and hp).

```
# download pacman package if not installed, otherwise load it
if(!require(pacman)) install.packages(pacman)

# loads relevant packages using the pacman package
pacman::p_load(
  magrittr,  # for pipes 
  gtsummary) # for tables
  
  
  
  mtcars %>% 
    lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, data = .) %>% 
    tbl_regression()
```

The table currently looks like this...

[image]

Comment: Check out the include= argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Daniel's suggestion:

```
library(gtsummary)

mtcars %>% 
  lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, data = .) %>% 
  tbl_regression(include = c("cyl","disp"))
```